# How do I use scipy.weave.inline together with external C libraries?

Tags: python, c, inline, scipy

I am trying to understand weave.inline to wrap C code in my Python programs. The code below simply takes the Numpy array and multiplicates all of its elements by 2.

**inl.py**

```
import numpy
import scipy.weave

a = numpy.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
N = a.shape[0]

print a
code = \
  """
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    a[i] = a[i] * 2;
  }
  """

scipy.weave.inline(code, ['a','N'])
print a
```

Then I want to carry some functions from inline code to external libraries. Let it be the trivial multiplication by 2. So I create two files:

**mult.c**

```
#include "mult.h"

float mult(float n)
{
  return n * 2;
}
```

**mult.h**

```
float inc(float n);
```

Now I want to use function mult in my inline code. But I don't know how do I link my C files with Python inline code. I tried to compile C files as shared library and pass them as headers and libraries in weave, but that was in vain. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have successfully done this, calling math functions from R via weave.inline() code (under Ubuntu Linux).

First, compile your C functions as a shared library.  In my case, I grabbed a recent release of R from CRAN, and did

```
./configure --enable-R-static-lib --enable-static --with-readline=no
cd src/nmath/standalone/
make
```

You should now have a file called `libRmath.so`.  If `libpath` is a string with the directory that holds `libRmath.so`, you can do something like

```
code = 'return_val = pbinom(100, 20000, 100./20000., 0, 1);'
support_code = 'extern "C" double pbinom(double x, double n, double p, int lower_tail, int log_p);'
weave.inline(code, support_code=support_code,
    library_dirs=[libpath], libraries=["Rmath"], runtime_library_dirs=[libpath])
```

Note a couple things.  The header declarations have to go in `support_code`, not `code` (I don't know why), and they have to be prefixed with `extern "C"` because they're C code, not C++ (this is standard).  It should be possible to include headers files instead of using `support_code` (check the docs for weave.inline), but I haven't tried it.  The library name is `Rmath`, but the shared library file is `libRmath.so`, in the usual Unix convention.  And the path to the library is specified twice, once for linking, and once for execution.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

put the source of mult.c and mult.h in a string object called extra_code, then add the following line in your .weave invocation

```
support_code=extra_code,
```

there is also the option to include standard libraries as follows:

```
headers = ["<math.h>"]
```

enjoy